# The most general $SU(2)$ invariant spin $\frac{1}{2}$ hamiltonian on 5 sites

Tags: solid-state-physics, symmetry, hamiltonian, spin-chains

I have periodic chain of spins $s=\frac{1}{2}$. I want to know what is the most general $SU(2)$ invariant and translation invariant hamiltonian. 
My guess is:
$$\sum_i (j_1 S_i \cdot S_{i+1}+j_2 S_i \cdot S_{i+2} + j_3 (S_i \cdot S_{i+1})( S_{i+2} \cdot S_{i+3}) + j_4 (S_i \cdot S_{i+1})( S_{i+2} \cdot S_{i+4}) +j_5 (S_i \cdot S_{i+2})( S_{i+1} \cdot S_{i+3})).$$ Can somebody confirm this or point me to some literature where this is discussed? Also I would be interested in a derivation of this result.

Comment: You are specifically interested in 5 sites?  Where is the relevance that it is a "periodic chain" then?

Comment: I am interested in small systems. So first, I am trying to construct this hamiltonian on 5 sites. The relevance of periodicity is that it imposes translation symmetry.

Comment: Ah - so you are looking for an SU(2) invariant **and translational invariant** Hamiltonian.  You should state that.  ---  Note that if you e.g. want to parametrize this Hamiltonian numerically, there should be ways to automatize this without deriving the explicit form.

Comment: I don't think you Hamiltonian includes terms like $\vec S\cdot(\vec S\times \vec S)$.

Comment: Indeed, you are right about this term. Time reversal symmerty removes it, right?

Comment: Yes, but do you *want* time reversal?

Comment: Your Hamiltonian is non-local, and it violates the Lieb-Robinson bound.

Answer (score 0):

You must impose some constraints otherwise the space of invariant Hamiltonians would be much larger (then the five parameters that you consider).  It's dimension would be the dimension of the $J=0$ sector which is exponentially large.

Typical constraints are

1) geometric locality (interaction takes place only between nearby particles) and

2) few body interaction. This expresses the fact that interaction between many particles at the same time are rare and the most usual choice is to have only two particles per interaction. But of course in principle $k$-body interactions are possible.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand that nonlocal interactions don't describe real physics very well, but I am really interested in a most general hamiltonian that only respects SU2 symmetry and translational symmetry. Therefore I do not wish to impose locality. I also understand that such hamiltonian is very complex, that's why I restricted myself to a small system, i.e 5 sites.

Comment: Then the answer is: any Hermitian matrix in the $J=0$ sector.

Comment: By the way, I should add that my argument works for an even number of sites

Comment: Ah and then you wanna impose translational symmetry too. I didn't see that. If you want a *practical* way to build a Hamiltonian with such symmetries (or find the value of a certain Hamiltonian in this sector) I could do that

Comment: Well, I have a su2 and translation invariant hamiltonian is some weird basis and I want to interpret it in terms of spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ interactions. In short, I am looking for a basis of operators.